# customer_id is not populated on transaction tender

Tags: square-connect

I've noticed that in nearly all cases that after receiving a webhook notification and retrieving the payment and correlating transaction, that the tender(s) on the transaction are missing the customer_id.

On rare occasions it is populated.  At some point in the future it seems that this is being added, as old transactions have the field set.

Is this a bug?  Can someone explain/document the expected behavior?
Are there any plans for this to be set in real-time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We'll improve the documentation around that feature. The customer_id field is optionally added by the merchant in the event that the merchant wants to track customers, and is only included in the response when the merchant has added it. However, the field is required in the event that the customer_card_id parameter mentioned here https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-charge   is provided.

Comment: I understand that part, I'm actually testing with my own Square Merchant account and I've tried adding the customer to the transaction before, during, and after adding items.  I've tried different customers with different fields (i.e. e-mail / phone) set.  I have detected no repeatable pattern as to why it shows up on some transaction and not others.  

I just checked and all the transactions I completed earlier today now have the customer_ids.  If you could provide some detail around the timing specification that would be great.